# How can I add arrays in an image

Tags: matlab

I have image with size of 106X351 logical.When I want to sum all of arrays in this image, I've faced with this error "Index exceeds matrix dimensions."

s=sum(im);

Is there any function that I can use?

Comment: If your error is in that line, most likely you have a variable named `sum`. Try clearing the workspace and change the name of any variables named sum in you script and give it a try :-)

Comment: Definitely the problem is what RobertP said. Else that sum will totally work. No doubt there.

Comment: Thank you so much, Robert & Ander. It works.

Answer (score 1):

If your error is in that line, most likely you have a variable named
sum. Try clearing the workspace and change the name of any variables
named sum in you script and give it a try

Comment: I made this CW since I don't think it's rep-worthy. @sahandmz: It would be nice if you accept the answer so that the question doesn't appear unanswered on the front page. Thanks =)